# How do I fix the two black lines on my mesh?

Tags: objects, vertices, edges, faces

I pressed F to connect an edge between vertices in order to create a straight line where I could mark a crease. But The new lines created by pressing F are behaving weirdly. Here's a blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l4dyZFzKD4OYRlZNAnEdIrgnLw0WsxTN/view [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have edges going across faces.

[image: broken faces]

Remove the edges that go across these faces by selecting them, pressing <kbd>x</kbd> and selecting delete edges.

[image: Delete edges]

Next select the vertices that were left behind and press <kbd>j</kbd> key to join these vertices

[image: Join vertices]

The end result is quite good.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Connect Vertex Path** <kbd>J</kbd>, which split the existing face.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/connect_vertex_path.html

Instead of **New Edge/Face from Vertices** <kbd>F</kbd>, which created a new edge *on top* of the face.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/make_face_edge.html